# Ruby regex match vs ===

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm doing the Bob exercise in ruby track from exercism, I get all the test passing except one:

```
1) Failure:
BobTest#test_multiple_line_question [bob_test.rb:129]:
Bob hears "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo.", and...
Expected: "Whatever."
  Actual: "Sure."

25 runs, 25 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

This is my code:

```
# Class emulating teenager answers
class Bob
  def self.hey(remark)
    case remark
    when /^[A-Z| ]+\?$/
      'Calm down, I know what I\'m doing!'
    when /^.*\?[ ]*$/, /^\n.*?\nNo\./m
      'Sure.'
    when /^.*[A-Z]+!+.*$/, /^[A-Z]+[A-Z| ]*!*$/
      'Whoa, chill out!'
    when /^[ |\t]*$/
      'Fine. Be that way!'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end
  end
end
```

So I do not know how to handle this regular expression:

```
    q = "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo."
    #=> "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo."
    puts q
    # Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?
    # No.

    q.match?(/^\n.*?\nNo\./m)
    #=> true

    [4] pry(main)> [5] pry(main)> Bob.hey(q)
=> "Sure."
[7] pry(main)> class Bob
  def self.hey(remark)
    case remark
    when /^[A-Z| ]+\?$/
      'Calm down, I know what I\'m doing!'
    when /^.*\?[ ]*$/, /^\n.*?\nNo\./m
      'Sure.'
    when /^.*[A-Z]+!+.*$/, /^[A-Z]+[A-Z| ]*!*$/
      'Whoa, chill out!'
    when /^[ |\t]*$/
      'Fine. Be that way!'
    else
      'Whatever.'
    end
  end
end
[7] pry(main)* => :hey
[8] pry(main)> Bob.hey(q)
=> "Sure."
```

The problem is that the minitest doesn't work, and I do not understand why:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'bob'

# Common test data version: 1.4.0 ca79943
class BobTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_stating_something
    # # skip
    remark = "Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to."
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to.", and..}
  end

  def test_shouting
    # skip
    remark = "WATCH OUT!"
    assert_equal "Whoa, chill out!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "WATCH OUT!", and..}
  end

  def test_shouting_gibberish
    # skip
    remark = "FCECDFCAAB"
    assert_equal "Whoa, chill out!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "FCECDFCAAB", and..}
  end

  def test_asking_a_question
    # skip
    remark = "Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?", and..}
  end

  def test_asking_a_numeric_question
    # skip
    remark = "You are, what, like 15?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "You are, what, like 15?", and..}
  end

  def test_asking_gibberish
    # skip
    remark = "fffbbcbeab?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "fffbbcbeab?", and..}
  end

  def test_talking_forcefully
    # skip
    remark = "Let's go make out behind the gym!"
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Let's go make out behind the gym!", and..}
  end

  def test_using_acronyms_in_regular_speech
    # skip
    remark = "It's OK if you don't want to go to the DMV."
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "It's OK if you don't want to go to the DMV.", and..}
  end

  def test_forceful_question
    # skip
    remark = "WHAT THE HELL WERE YOU THINKING?"
    assert_equal "Calm down, I know what I'm doing!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "WHAT THE HELL WERE YOU THINKING?", and..}
  end

  def test_shouting_numbers
    # skip
    remark = "1, 2, 3 GO!"
    assert_equal "Whoa, chill out!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "1, 2, 3 GO!", and..}
  end

  def test_no_letters
    # skip
    remark = "1, 2, 3"
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "1, 2, 3", and..}
  end

  def test_question_with_no_letters
    # skip
    remark = "4?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "4?", and..}
  end

  def test_shouting_with_special_characters
    # skip
    remark = "ZOMG THE %^*@\#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!"
    assert_equal "Whoa, chill out!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "ZOMG THE %^*@\#$(*^ ZOMBIES ARE COMING!!11!!1!", and..}
  end

  def test_shouting_with_no_exclamation_mark
    # skip
    remark = "I HATE THE DMV"
    assert_equal "Whoa, chill out!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "I HATE THE DMV", and..}
  end

  def test_statement_containing_question_mark
    # skip
    remark = "Ending with ? means a question."
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Ending with ? means a question.", and..}
  end

  def test_non_letters_with_question
    # skip
    remark = ":) ?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears ":) ?", and..}
  end

  def test_prattling_on
    # skip
    remark = "Wait! Hang on. Are you going to be OK?"
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Wait! Hang on. Are you going to be OK?", and..}
  end

  def test_silence
    # skip
    remark = ""
    assert_equal "Fine. Be that way!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "", and..}
  end

  def test_prolonged_silence
    # skip
    remark = "          "
    assert_equal "Fine. Be that way!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "          ", and..}
  end

  def test_alternate_silence
    # skip
    remark = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
    assert_equal "Fine. Be that way!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", and..}
  end

  def test_multiple_line_question
    # skip
    remark = "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo."
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo.", and..}
  end

  def test_starting_with_whitespace
    # skip
    remark = "         hmmmmmmm..."
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "         hmmmmmmm...", and..}
  end

  def test_ending_with_whitespace
    # skip
    remark = "Okay if like my  spacebar  quite a bit?   "
    assert_equal "Sure.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "Okay if like my  spacebar  quite a bit?   ", and..}
  end

  def test_other_whitespace
    # skip
    remark = "\n\r \t"
    assert_equal "Fine. Be that way!", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "\n\r \t", and..}
  end

  def test_non_question_ending_with_whitespace
    # skip
    remark = "This is a statement ending with whitespace      "
    assert_equal "Whatever.", Bob.hey(remark), %q{Bob hears "This is a statement ending with whitespace      ", and..}
  end
end
```

Comment: I think `^.*\?[ ]*$` will match `Does this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?`. Isn't that why it fails?

Comment: `case` works the other way round – `case remark` and `when /^[A-Z| ]+\?$/` results in `/^[A-Z| ]+\?$/ === remark`. The case-object becomes the right hand operand and the when-patterns become the left hand operands for `===`.

Comment: Read `===` as "subsumes". The left operand is the more general case; the right operand is a specific case that should fit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters are backwards. `===`, in ruby, is a slightly odd operation because it's not always symmetric - i.e. just because `a === b`, it's not necessarily true that `b === a`.

In this case, note that:

```
/^\n.*?\nNo\./ === "\nDoes this cryogenic chamber make me look fat?\nNo."
  => true
```

(And `String === Regex`) **always** returns false.)

This is the order in which `case` places the arguments, and explains why you're seeing that result.

However, I don't really know how to "fix" your code since I don't know what behaviour you expect! Maybe the test is wrong? Maybe the regex is wrong? Maybe the `case` statement is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I totally forget that, but now the problem is taht then minitest doesn't work, but all the other thinks are working

Comment: @anquegim As I said above, I don't know what you mean by "doesn't work". The code is doing exactly what you told it to (there's no bug in the ruby language here!), and I don't know what else you expect it to do. All I see is a failing test. Is the test wrong, or is the code wrong? What behaviour do you expect the code to have?

Comment: Well I want that the code pass the tests, and I do not anderstand why separetely it works, but no whithin the tests

Comment: Why do you say "it works separately"? The string matches `/^\n.*?\nNo\./`, and therefore - as defined in your code - the `'Sure.'` branch of the `case` statement is evaluated. Your test, on the other hand, expects a return value of `'Whatever.'`. So the test fails. If the code is wrong, then why is it wrong? I still don't know what rules your code is supposed to be applying.

Comment: Ahh, Sometimes I'm so silly, sorry for teh incovenience, I was focused on that wrong thing